# Typeahead with remote database and dynamically load a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me on this issue!! .. Providing auto suggest using twitter bootstrap typeahead based on the value typed in the text box.. based on the item selected from the suggestions shown in bootstrap an label dynamically shows the address and phone number(already in array ) below the text box and an drop down is loaded based on company_id.

The main thing is I am struct with fetching array associative id's and values's

my html is

```
<input class=" half" type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" size="30" />
```

jscript is

```
$('#company_name').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/get_company_details.php',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            async: false,
            data: 'q=' + query,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                var convert = JSON.parse(result);
                typeahead.process(convert);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

my php file

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rsd )) {   
    $arr[] =array(
        'company_name' => $row[1],
        'company_id' => $row[0],
        'company_reg_addr_line1' => $row[2],
        'company_reg_addr_line2' => $row[3],
        'company_reg_city' => $row[4],
        'company_reg_city_id' => $row[10],
        'company_reg_pincode' => $row[5],
        'company_billing_addr_line1' => $row[6],
        'company_billing_addr_line2' => $row[7],
        'company_billing_city' => $row[8],
        'company_billing_city_id' => $row[11],
        'company_billing_pincode' => $row[9],
        'company_phone_number' => $row[12]
    );
}  

$convert_name = json_encode($arr);

echo $convert_name;
```

The array iam getting is

```
[
    {
        "company_name": "vinod company ",
        "company_id": "2",
        "company_reg_addr_line1": "first line",
        "company_reg_addr_line2": "second line",
        "company_reg_city": "66",
        "company_reg_city_id": "www.vinodproduction.com",
        "company_reg_pincode": "122122",
        "company_billing_addr_line1": "third line",
        "company_billing_addr_line2": "fourth line",
        "company_billing_city": "67",
        "company_billing_city_id": "909099009",
        "company_billing_pincode": "121212",
        "company_phone_number": "1"
    },
    {
        "company_name": "Vignesh",
        "company_id": "4",
        "company_reg_addr_line1": "iji",
        "company_reg_addr_line2": "ij",
        "company_reg_city": "83",
        "company_reg_city_id": "j",
        "company_reg_pincode": "0",
        "company_billing_addr_line1": "ji",
        "company_billing_addr_line2": "j",
        "company_billing_city": "83",
        "company_billing_city_id": "hjh",
        "company_billing_pincode": "0",
        "company_phone_number": "1"
    }
]
```

iF I change the array like ["kumar productions","vinod company"," vignesh  merchant"]  the typeahead is working fine
but I need to send the address through the array itself!!!

so I changed the array which i mentioned below.the type ahead itself not working.

```
[{"company_name":"vinod company ","company_id":"2","company_reg_addr_line1":"first line","company_reg_addr_line2":"second line","company_reg_city":"66","company_reg_city_id":"www.vinodproduction.com","company_reg_pincode":"122122","company_billing_addr_line1":"third line","company_billing_addr_line2":"fourth line","company_billing_city":"67","company_billing_city_id":"909099009","company_billing_pincode":"121212","company_phone_number":"1"},{"company_name":"Vignesh","company_id":"4","company_reg_addr_line1":"iji","company_reg_addr_line2":"ij","company_reg_city":"83","company_reg_city_id":"j","company_reg_pincode":"0","company_billing_addr_line1":"ji","company_billing_addr_line2":"j","company_billing_city":"83","company_billing_city_id":"hjh","company_billing_pincode":"0","company_phone_number":"1"}]
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly?  Perhaps you needn't `JSON.parse` the result as you ahve already specified the data as being JSON in the ajax options.

Comment: The exact problem is need to display the address below the text box after slecting from the auto suggest.

Comment: Depending on the version of bootstrap you are using this is a bit tricky as version 3 has dropped support of typeahead and you are encouraged to use the separate library by Twitter http://tosbourn.com/upgrading-from-bootstraps-typeahead-to-typeahead-js/  otherwise have a look at the docs here http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try your typeahead array like this:

**Source**:

```
[
  { ID: 1, Name: 'Toronto' }, { ID: 2, Name: 'Montreal' },
  { ID: 3, Name: 'New York' }, {ID: 4,Name: 'Buffalo' },
  { ID: 5, Name: 'Boston' }, { ID: 6, Name: 'Columbus' },
  { ID: 7, Name: 'Dallas' }, { ID: 8, Name: 'Vancouver'},
  { ID:9, Name: 'Seattle' },{ID: 10, Name:'Los Angeles' }
]
```

`display:'Name', val:'ID'`

After choosing the particular company you can get the respective company id from the textbox and do the logic of fetching the company details using the selected company id.